Invalid SKU Handling for Linked Products in Magento
In Magento, it’s possible to save a product SKU as "0." However, an issue occurs when this product is added as a linked product (such as Related Products, Up-Sells, or Cross-Sells) to another product. When attempting to make changes to the main product, it triggers an error: "The linked product SKU is invalid. Verify the data and try again."
This issue arises in the file Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\Repository, specifically in the public function save, where the following condition is used:
 (!$entity->getLinkedProductSku()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('The linked product SKU is invalid. Verify the 
   data and try again.'));
 }




One approach to resolve this is by adding an explicit check for the SKU value to prevent saving it as "0." For instance, you could add a validation condition to prevent saving a SKU as "0" at the time of saving the product.
